# how to do scientific research?

Tags: independent-study

yes.I am a graduate student but i don't know how to do scientific research.My speed of scientific research is slower.I really need others to help me.Can you give me some advice or methods? I really want to how i can open my research.Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is too broad. Basically, you read about a topic, and think of ideas to improve the existing solutions. Try to focus your question on a more specific problem. See [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Also, statements like "I really want to know answers quickly" will probably reduce the amount and speed of answers you get.

Comment: @wimi I interpreted this as "I want to get answers to my research questions quickly", which truthfully isn't much better.

Comment: @wimi thank you! I first come here.I may take many grammar mistakes,please don't mind these.Can you tell me why my statements is wrong.hahaha,i don't understand it ..finally,i sincerely thank your comments.

Comment: @xLeitix thank you so much.i will correct my statements immediately.

Comment: @user118304 Your question has not been closed due to your grammar mistakes (although they probably didn't help). It has been closed because it is *way* too broad - most of the PhD experience is about learning how to conduct research. In a nutshell, you need to give us a much more narrow question, otherwise we cannot answer within the scope of a Q&A site. That said, Allure's answer is probably more productive than continuing here - go to your faculty advisor, and ask him how to get started in your field.

Comment: @xLeitix OK.I understand your meaning. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Speak to your advisor, who's there to teach you this. He/she will also be more familiar with your exact research, the immediate goals, the steps you need to take to get there, etc.

Comment: IN the fact,my advisor is very professional,he helps me a lot.But sometimes,i want to know  how to aright open or start a research.he always tells me "i only see results".i support his views,but i want to know how i can do.i don't understand whether i say clear to you.hahaha.now i suspect myself,i don't tell this thing to my teacher.